# javascript matching for validation for password

Tags: javascript, html

I want to validate an input for password using the .match method.
Password needs to have at least an uppercase and a number, must start with a letter.
Can i put all these qualifications in one single "if" statement or i need to use more match statements.
I tried something like this, but doesn't work

```
if (!y.match(/^[a-zA-Z]\d{1,}[A-Z]{1,}$/))
```

I changed the code to the following:

```
function validate(){
    var x,y,z,abv="";
    x = document.getElementById("name").value;
    if (x.length<6){
            abv+="user name too short<br />";
    } else {
        abv+="validated<br />";
    }       
    y = document.getElementById("password").value;
    if (y.length<8||!y.match(!/^(?=\D*\d)(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])[a-zA-Z]/){
        abv+="Password do not pass validation!<br />";
    } 
    document.getElementById("aka").innerHTML = abv;
```

}

Is there any problem with the code? I ran the page with inputs not passing the validation, but error messages don't show up. When I took out the .match part, the name will validate and error message shows up.

Comment: `{1,}` can just be `+`

Comment: You have 2 problems. First with your regexp. I don't think it'll work just as you need. Second is that match function returns an Array, so check the return length in your condition.

Comment: @ThiagoBonfante When there isn't a match, it returns `null`, which is a falsy value. It would work, but it wouldn't be efficient.

Comment: Please don't force me to use insecure passwords

Comment: @JanDvorak You should elaborate on what's wrong with their requirements. Your comment isn't too helpful.

Comment: @4castle I admit I misread the regex, but still - requiring the first character be a letter is pointless, even if it removes less than one bit of entropy - less than the other requirements

Comment: @4castle you're right, it'll return null. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use lookeaheads so that the number and uppercase letter can be in any order. You also don't need to anchor with `$` unless you're going to validate the rest of the characters.

```
if (!/^(?=\D*\d)(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])[a-zA-Z]/.test(y))
```

1. `^` assert beginning of string
2. `(?=\D*\d)` assert that a digit is somewhere in the string
3. `(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])` assert that an uppercase letter is somewhere in the string
4. `[a-zA-Z]` assert that the first character is a letter.

The lookaheads in 2 & 3 don't advance the cursor. That's why 4 is referring to the first character.

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pZ9nI8/1)

```js
function isValid(str) {
  return /^(?=\D*\d)(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])[a-zA-Z]/.test(str)
}

console.log(isValid("aB7"));
console.log(isValid("a7B"));
console.log(isValid("A%9"));
```

Comment: can you talk explain a bit more about the code, like which does what, what is lookaheads?

Comment: @Andy A lookahead verifies that the following characters match a certain pattern, without actually matching the characters. You can Google for more info. Look at the explanation pane on the [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/pZ9nI8/1) to see a breakdown of the regex.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I understand your code, it is exactly what I wanted, but can you take a look at my edited post, when I implement this, the html page does not work as I expected.

Comment: @Andy Please use the debugger on your browser. You are missing a closing `)` on the `if` statement. Also, don't use `match`, use `test`.

Answer (score 0):

While you *can* put everything in one Regex, I would seriously take a moment to ask: "Should you?"

Let's say your boss decides to praise you for how well you did the password validation thing. "Oh, and by the way, can you make it so you can't have the same number three times?"

Sure, you might be able to add it to your regex (`(?!.*(\d)\1\1)`) but do you see how it can easily get out of control?

Instead, stick with individual checks. Like so:

```
if( false); // dummy entry so that all tests begin "else if" for easier commenting out
else if( !y.match(/[A-Z]/)) alert("Password must contain an uppercase letter!");
else if( !y.match(/\d/)) alert("Password must contain a number!");
else if( !y.match(/^[a-z]/i)) alert("Password must start with a letter!");
// add more cases here, e.g.
// else if( y.length < 8) alert("Password must be 8 characters or longer!");
else alert("Password is OK!");
```

Using this you can actually tell the user what it is about their password that your system doesn't like, allowing them to correct that without having to take frustrated guesses. It also allows you to add and remove conditions at any time and with ease.

I strongly recommend this option...

Well, that's a lie. I strongly recommend letting the user have whatever (insecure) password they want. You're hashing it (right?) so you've fulfilled your duty of keeping their password safe. It's on the user to use a safe password in the first place.